# Range query on a subdocument array property

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of recipes that have servings array. Each serving has a numeric energy property. I need to select all recipes with at least one serving that has energy that falls into the given range.

For example I have 2 recipes:

```
{
  title: 'Greek salad',
  servings: [
    {
      energy: 100
    },
    {
      energy: 150
    }
  ]
},
{
  title: 'Smashed potatoes',
  servings: [
    {
      energy: 150
    },
    {
      energy: 200
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looking for a query that would match only `Greek salad` given the range is `90..110`, and both recipes for `140..160` range.

The best I came up with:

```
db.recipes.find({$and: [
    {'servings.energy' : {$gt: 90}}, 
    {'servings.energy' : {$lt: 110}}
   ]}
```

matches 2 results, which is not what is expect.

PS. There is a 1M+ records in the collections and I'm looking for a query that would run entirely out of index. Maybe I could change the data structure somehow to satisfy my needs?

Comment: Is the following result correct for the range 140..160?
{
  title: 'Greek salad',
  servings: [
    {
      energy: 150
    }
  ]
},
{
  title: 'Smashed potatoes',
  servings: [
    {
      energy: 150
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @VolodymyrSynytskyi sure, but the query should perform as fast as possible. There's a million of records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the mongodb [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator:

```
db.getCollection('recipes').aggregate([
  {$project: {
    recipe: "$$ROOT",
    servings: {$filter: {
        input: "$recommendedServings",
        as: "serving",
        cond: {
            $and: [{$gt: ['$$serving.energy', 400]}, 
                   {$lt: ['$$serving.energy', 410]}]
        } 
     }}
   }},
   {$match: {"servings.0": {$exists: true}}}
 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following aggregation query to get the result that you are expecting:

```
    db.testso.aggregate([
                  {$match: { "servings.energy": { $gt: 90, $lt:110 }}},   
                  {$unwind:"$servings"},
                  {$match: { "servings.energy": { $gt: 90, $lt:110 }}}
]);
```

1. First match the records based on your criteria - this will take both the records from your subdocument.
2. Unwind the records now based on the servings array.
3. Now match the records based on your criteria again.

Comment: Cannot afford unwinding since i'm having like a half of a million of records

Comment: Updated the query, check again now.

Comment: Good try, but the first match actually matches all records in my case, so it is essentially the same as unwinding the whole collection